# Proof involving the functional equation $ f ( x + n ) = f ( x ) f ( n ) $ for $ x \in \mathbb R $ and $ n \in \mathbb N $

Tags: solution-verification, functional-equations

I'm trying to prove that if
$$ f ( x + n ) = f ( x ) f ( n ) $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $ and $ n \in \mathbb N $, then it also holds for $ x , n \in \mathbb R $. One "argument" I came up with was regarding the symmetry. There's no reason why one should be constrained to the integers, while the other can be any real number, but that's not a proper argument.

---

Another thing I thought of is this: If we set $ n = 1 $ then we get
$$ f ( x + 1 ) = f ( 1 ) f ( x ) \tag 1 \label 1 $$
which is true for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Now, if we instead set $ x = 1 $ then we get $ f ( n + 1 ) = f ( n ) f ( 1 ) $ which must also be true for $ n \in \mathbb R $ because \eqref{1} is. What keeps me from being satisfied is that $ n \in \mathbb R $ *under the assumption* that $ x = 1 $.

Is my reasoning valid or not?

**Edit:** Forgot an important bit of information: $ f $ is a *continuous* function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is not valid; you are noticing that if $x$ is an integer then $n$ could vary anywhere in the reals, but this is just stating that the relation $f(x+n)=f(x)f(n)$ has a symmetry where we swap $x$ and $n$ and doesn't tell us anything about whether $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ when both are real.

More directly, the statement you're trying to prove is false, so obviously your proof of it is not valid. Let $f$ be the function 
$$f(x)=a^{x+g(x)}$$
where $g(x)$ is a function such that $g(x+1)=g(x)$ and $g(0)=0$, and clearly, for any integer $n$, it holds that $g(x+n)=g(x)$ and $g(n)=0$. Then, for integer $n$ and real $x$, it olds that
$$f(x+n)=a^{x+n+g(x+n)}$$
but we can write $x+n+g(x+n)=(x+g(x))+(n+g(n))$ so we have

$$f(x+n)=a^{x+g(x)}a^{n+g(n)}=f(x)f(n).$$
However, it's easy to choose reals for which $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ does not hold; for instance, choosing $x=y=\frac{1}2$ and letting $k=g(\frac{1}2)+\frac{1}2$, we get
$$f(1)=f\left(\frac{1}2\right)f\left(\frac{1}2\right)$$
$$a = a^k\cdot a^k = a^{2k}$$
which does not hold if $a\neq 1$ and $g(\frac{1}2)\neq 0$.